# PHP Semaphores causing failures?

Tags: php, linux, semaphore

Our web servers have seen random PHP request failures for some requests that involve semaphores. We traced and suspected the request died somewhere due to sem_*() functions in PHP but we were unable to dig anything useful from the error log. We are on PHP 5.3.6 on 64-bit Linux machines. The code runs like this:

```
    $sem_id = @sem_get(123457, 1);
    if (!$sem_id) return;
    $sem_retval = @sem_acquire($sem_id);
    if (!$sem_retval) return;
    $shm_id = shmop_open(ftok('/some/path', 'h'), 'c', 0666, 8192);
    if ($shm_id === FALSE) { @sem_release($sem_id); return; }
    $str = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 8192);
    // ... some operations that may result in changes to $data
    if ($data_updated) {
        shmop_write($shm_id, str_pad(serialize($data), 8192, "\0"), 0);
    }
    @shmop_close($shm_id);
    @sem_release($sem_id);
    @sem_remove($sem_id);
```

This snippet is in an area having very frequent access with concurrency. In fact this is placed in a StreamWrapper implementation we developed internally for supporting our own operations. It appears like concurrency is related because we tested sequentially and did not reveal any issues.

Any insights as to what may be the cause? Also, I am not sure what sem_remove() is doing as I found no system call counterpart.

P.S. We took away all statements that contain sem_*() and seems like we no longer experience the issue.

Comment: Can you define "random PHP request failures" more clearly?

Comment: OK. Processing of the PHP request terminates in an abrupt manner for unknown reasons. This did not happen every time. As mentioned, it occasionally occurred with the same set of parameters, that's what I meant by being "random".

The execution path includes a number of application-specific processing that were not shown. However, when it needs to access some sort of file storage facility, it goes through a StreamWrapper implementation that contains the quoted snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to STOP using the @-operator, right away. This masks any error, and makes it silently ignored, even if it causes a fatal exit.

The @ operator is one of the worst features of PHP.

If an error happens, because you're using the @ operator, you've got no way of knowing what it was, or even that it happened at all, because your script will either plough on regardless, or exit with no dignostic data. This applies even if you've got error logging set up and error_reporting set to its maximum.